# Is slowdown caused by Meltdown/Spectre patches expected to happen when vm or the virtualisation host gets updated?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I have `Ubuntu server` vms running on `Ubuntu server` hosts with `Kvm` as hypervisor.

I know that installing the kernel patches for Meltdown/Spectre may cause the systems to become slower.

Is this slowdown expected to happen when vms get patched or when the virtualisation host gets updated? (Or will both updates cause slowdown?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Is this slowdown expected to happen when vms get patched or when the virtualisation host gets updated? (Or will both updates cause slowdown?)` - The slowdown is expected on the systems that have the patch installed, whether they be virtual or physical.. so yes... both.